# Having application post to a wall of a Random Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using php sdk to have an app post to a wall of a random page as an app, not admin.

```
$facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed/', 'post', $attachment);
```

Error returned is:

```
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

The facebook object already has a app id and app secret, so access token for app is set, yet it won't allow the app to post to a page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I hate to ask a potentially stupid question, but the error is 'the user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action'... has the user actually given you authorization to post on their behalf to pages? (the `publish_stream` permission)

Comment: @Igy no question is stupid :) The issue is that I'm posting to a page feed, not user feed so I'm not sure how to give an app this authorization. How do I authorize an app to post to a specific page? I could not find any information in docs. I tried creating a link to requst auth token, but it always logs you in as a user, not a page. If I user gives the app permission then app can post to that wall as user, but not as app.

Comment: The user who is using your app needs to give your app permission to post on their behalf - if you want to post as the page itself you should read the page login docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/

Comment: @Igy I would like to post as an app (so that app name appears as poster) or as a page (so that page name appears as a poster) I don't want to post as page admin (as in: I don't want to have admins name appear as the author of the post) So I went to graph explorer and with my user access token retrieved the page access token. Then I'm setting this page access token into a facebook obkect along with app secret and id and trying to post to that page, but get the error I posted in post. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can't post as an app, and to post as a page, you need to follow the page login steps i linked earlier - are you sure you're not trying to post to a user's feed using the page access token, or something else which isn't possible?

Comment: @Igy turns out I was using the wrong access token after all, instead of apps access token to page generated by graph tool, I was using user's access token to page. Your help lead me to the solution. Can you please add your second comment as answer so I can select it as solution? Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user who is using your app needs to give your app permission to post on their behalf - if you want to post as the page itself you should read the page login docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page and ensure you're definitely using the Page Access Token to make the post

Comment: do you know by any chance how I can extent the life of this access token? It's expiring in an hour. I created [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128732/how-can-long-lived-access-token-be-retrieved-for-a-page-via-graph-explorer) if you can answer it I'd really appreciate: