# How can long-lived access token be retrieved for a page via graph explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I want to allow an app to post as a page, so I used graph api to get access token to the page but it has one hour expiry.

Is there a way to retrieve long term access tokens via graph api?

P.S. I tried to use the endpoint for exchanging the short term access token with long term one and am getting OAuth error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a never expiring token for your fan page. Follow the simple steps:

1. Get the admin's(i.e. yours) extended token (2 months validity). Go though the link to get the extended token. Works with perfection:

   [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation/9035036#9035036)
2. Using this token, Get the list of pages/apps-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/USER_ID/accounts");
   ```
3. Get the never expiring access token for any page-

   ```
   $facebook->api("/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token");
   ```

(You can use [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check the validity of the token.)

Comment: Can I obtain admin's extended token via graph explorer?

Comment: Of course you can. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/#step1

Comment: It seems like I was doing exactly this and it's was not working, now I tried again and it worked. Just strange. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can getting 60 days access_token by following code.**

```
$user = $facebook->getUser(); 
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken(); //long-live access_token 60 days
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```